# ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol multiple protocol performance

Tags: .net, .net-4.6

Using .net 4.6
When setting multiple protocols to access an api will trying all protocols affect the latency of the call ?

example:
ervicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: No, this is only used once, at connection-time to negotiate the protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all versions before TLS 1.2 are effectively frowned upon these days, It's questionable to include the earlier versions in new development anyway. However, to answer your question:

> will trying all protocols affect

You should be aware that for TLS, the client's first message just says "this is the highest protocol version I support", and the server's first reply either agrees that version<sup>1</sup> or says "I only support a lower version". At that point, the client can agree to continue with the server's replied version or report a failure to connect.

There aren't multiple attempts, just one message in each direction.

---

<sup>1</sup>If the server finds that version acceptable. It's got the first chance to refuse to continue if it's configured versions doesn't include the client's requested version or any lower versions.